# How to process lots of messages on an Azure Queue with a WebJob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I have a pretty simple queue which happens to have heaps of messages on it (by design). Heaps can be "thousands" here.

Right now I'm playing around with using Azure Web Jobs with a Queue Trigger to process the messages. Works fine.

I'm worried about performance though. Let's assume my method that processes the message takes 1 sec. With so many messages, this all adds up.

I know I can manually POP a number of messages at the same time, then parallel process them .. but I'm not sure how we do this with web jobs?

I'm *assuming* the solution is to scale *out*? which means I would create 25 instances of the webjob? Or is there a better way where I can trigger on a message but pop 25 or so messages at once, then parallel them myself.

NOTE: Most of the delay is I/O (ie. a REST call to a 3rd party). not CPU.

I'm thinking -> create 25 tasks and `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` to process all the data that I get back.

So, what are my options?

NOTE #2: If the solution is scale out .. then I also need to make sure that my web job project only has *one* function in it, right? otherwise *all* the functions (read: triggers, etc) will also *all* be scaled out.

Comment: If you're exploring, I think this is a good candidate for azure-functions, you can probably decouple your code and make the triggers happen logically. Otherwise, azure-webjobs should work fine.

Comment: I'm just finding the TOOLING for functions .. very limiting. I basically don't want to do _any_ coding in a Web UI (sorry Monaco) because I want code to link to CI/CD. That's my current frustration :/

Comment: I feel you, the technology looks promising but the developing experience is still somewhat of a pain. If it helps, we've processed over 900 000 messages for a migration process using webjobs. It worked out pretty well (10 instances)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure WebJobs have a default configuration of processing 16 messages in parallel and this number is [configurable](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#config). The WebJobs framework internally creates 16 (or the configured `MaxDequeueCount`) copies of the your function and runs them in parallel.

Moreover, you can [launch multiple instances,](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/) i.e. scale out, of the Azure App Service/Website hosting the WebJob, subject to maximum of 20 instances. However, scaling out instances (unlike parallel Dequeue above) has a pricing impact so please check on that.

Thus theoretically you could be processing 24*20 = 480 messages in parallel by configuration alone on a standard WebJob function without any custom code.